# Frequent "Unable to generate ICNS file for push notification package" errors

Tags: macos, safari, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, safari-push-notifications

I keep getting

> Unable to generate ICNS file for push notification package

errors emailed to me for the Safari push notifications I've set up on my site. They work without errors for my laptop and any other I've tried, and I've read and re-read the instructions of how to make a push package and mine looks valid...

Reading in Apple's docs, it says the reason for this error is

> Your iconset may have malformed PNGs

but I've checked they are all just fine, no transparency, and again they work on my laptop... what the hell? Has anyone else out there experienced this or found a workaround? Anybody know of a push package testing tool?

Comment: The same problem here. In Safari 9 it was OK, but since Safari 10 I have this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case the error was caused by a wrong **DPI** of the images.

Solution: http://blog.pushpad.xyz/2016/11/unable-to-generate-icns-file-for-push-notification-package-solved/

Comment: Awesome, I bet this is what was wrong for me as well. Nice to have a free solution listed, I'll switch this to the accepted answer:)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up re-making all the icons using the Icons app from the mac app store, and then making the push package using [the push_package gem for ruby](https://github.com/SymmetricInfinity/push_package), and I no longer have the problem:)